# C program counting number of words with pointers inside a function

Tags: c, function, pointers, prototype

i have this block of code here: what im trying to do is to convert the part with the for loop and the index `[i]`, with pointers.

```
int main()
{ int i;
  int nwords;

    display_name();
    while (TRUE)
    {   printf("\nEnter a phrase :");
        gets(text);
        if (isEmpty(text))
            return 0;
        //  to be replaced in a function int wordcount(); - START  //
        nwords=0;
        for (i=0; text[i] ; i++)
            if (text[i]==' ' && text[i+1]!=' ')
                nwords++;
        nwords++;
        printf("Text contains %d words\n",nwords);
```

so i did it and until here works fine:

```
int main()
{ int i;
  int nwords;

    display_name();
    while (TRUE)
    {   printf("\nEnter a phrase :");
        gets_s(text);
        if (isEmpty(text))
            return 0;
        //  to be replaced in a function int wordcount(); - START  //
        nwords = 0;
        p = text;
        for (; *p != '\0'; p++)
            if (*p == ' ' && *p + 1 != ' ')
                nwords++;

        nwords++;
        printf("Text contains %d words\n",nwords);
```

but my question is how can i place this code in a function `wordcount()` and then call it from the `main()`? i placed the code in the function like this:

```
int wordcount(char *p){
    char text[256] ;
    int nwords;
    nwords = 0;

    p = text;
    for (; *p != '\0'; p++)
        if (*p == ' ' && *p + 1 != ' ')
            nwords++;
    return nwords;
}
```

and the prototype of the function:

```
int wordcount(char *p);
```

i call it like this but it does not count the words, just prints 0's.

```
int main()
{ int i;
  int nwords;

    display_name();
    while (TRUE)
    {   printf("\nEnter a phrase :");
        gets_s(text);
        if (isEmpty(text))
            return 0;
        //  to be replaced in a function int wordcount(); - START  //

        nwords = wordcount(text);
        printf("Text contains %d words\n",nwords);


Student Name : Rasmus Lerdorf
Enter a phrase :asd
Text contains 0 words

Enter a phrase :asdasd
Text contains 0 words

Enter a phrase :asd asdasd
Text contains 0 words

Enter a phrase :asd as as
Text contains 0 words

Enter a phrase :
```

Comment: Where is "text" defined in main?  You need to pass that to the function and remove locally-scoped test declaration.

Comment: `*p + 1` should be `*(p + 1)`

Comment: delete `char text[256] ;` and `p = text;` at `wordcount`. and `nwords = 0;` change to  `nwords = 1;`

Comment: `gets_s` needs size parameter.

Comment: iam sorry @OldProgrammer i had declared the char text[256] ; outside of main and i forgot to say it. it doesnt really matter if it is outside does it?

Comment: @user3629249 the first block is the original code! yes and it has the gets() function like this, but visual studio gets an error on that telling me that i have to change it in gets_s()

Comment: i defined it outside of main and i forgot to show to you. as i olready told it to @OldProgrammer

Comment: in the wordcount() function, the 'for' loop will fail for any of several reasons.  Here are two of those reasons.  1) the code is looking ahead of where the loop control is looking, so if the look ahead encounters a '\n' or a '\0' it will increment 'nwords'  even though there is no word.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY oh my God! thanks a lot! that was the fault. im trying to figure out why though... the `p = text;` was wrong inside the function

Comment: yes @user3629249 you are wright! how can i avoid that? with what change in my code?

Comment: perhaps check *(p_1) for '\n' and '\0' with an IF statement before incrementing nwords

Comment: @user3629249 you mean not with a for loop? just with an if statement? im thinking how this can be done... just my third time writing C.so any help would be much much appreciate. considering that this is just the first part of my program solution :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP approach is problematic in nature. (It assume the word exists in the first of input)
For example to be improved as follows.

```
int wordcount(const char *p){
    char prev = ' ';
    int nwords = 0;

    while(*p){
        if(isspace(prev) && !isspace(*p)){//isspace in <ctype.h>
            ++nwords;
        }
        prev = *p++;
    }
    return nwords;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much!! the code is absolutely perfect thanks a lot!

Comment: i didn'e even know the function `isspace` so this was very helpful. this way my program does not take into account the spaces anymore and as a result its functionality is perfect. thanks a lot Sir!

Answer (score 0):

```
int wordcount(char *text){   // here the pointer to the text is to be passed
char *p;  // no need to declare text again 
int nwords;
nwords = 0;

p = text;    
for (; *p != '\0'; p++)
    if (*p == ' ' && *p + 1 != ' ')
        nwords++;
return nwords;
}
```

I hope this will work now

Comment: this has the same problem with look-a-ahead as the OPs example

Comment: yes @Beowulf thanks this works too! the only thing is that i had to initialize to `nwords = 1;` instead of 0

Comment: parameters are passed by value, so need to copy the passed parameter to a local variable, just use the passed parameter to step through the text[] array.  For safety, and because text[] is globally visible, suggest 1) no passed parameter, 2) in for loop add '&& (p-text) < sizeof text' 3) initialize 'p' via ;p = text;;